# My character has split

Tags: objects

I was watching some tutorials (Darrin Lile) and I saw that i have to have my cursor in the centre in order to make it walk, so I did that, but my figure is cut in two now. Please tell me i do not have to create it again :'(
[image]

Comment: Were you using the Mirror Modifier during modeling? This can happen if you move the mesh inside edit mode and don't have Merge and Clipping enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try and see if that was the problmen :D